# When writing a cordova plugin for ios, how do I set the minimum ios platform in my podfile?

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, arcgis-runtime, cocoapods-1.1.1

I'm writing a cordova plugin and I have a framework I'm adding with cocoapod. The framework has a minimum ios requirement of version 13.0. When my pod file is generated it is defaulting to ios 10.0. How do I set the required IOS version in my plugin.xml?

plugin.xml snippets:

```
<engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=6.0.0" />
        <engine name="cordova-android" version=">=9.0.0" />
        <engine name="cordova-ios" version=">=5.1.0" />
</engines>

 <platform name="ios">
    ...
    <podspec>
        <config>
            <source url="https://cdn.cocoapods.org/"/>
        </config>
        <pods use-frameworks="true">                
            <pod name="ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS" spec="100.10" />
        </pods>
    </podspec>
</platform>
```

podfile created:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'testPluginApp' do
  project 'testPluginApp.xdodeproj'
  prod 'ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS', '100.10'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the iOS `10.0` platform is coming from the Cordova plugin.xml. Perhaps tied to the `5.1.0` version of `cordova-ios`?

I am not a Cordova developer, but you could try setting the `deployment-target` in your `config.xml`. See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/config_ref/) (scroll down to `deployment-target`).

A quick Google search would indicate that this is the expected way to resolve this, but that it is [a bit touchy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/search?q=deployment-target&type=issues).

Comment: I have traced through the cordova code and using the perference tag in your config.xml    <perferance name ="deployment-target" value="13.0" /> is the correct way to do this. But it doesn't work. I've submitted a bug issue on cordova's github page.

Comment: I've tested with multiple versions of cordova-ios 4.8, 5.1.1, and latest to see if the bug is fixed in a different version but it doesn't work in any of them.

Comment: Yeah. It seems not to work tremendously well. Some people have mentioned that they had to resort to manually modifying the podfile. I presume what you have above isn't copied and pasted directly though, because "preference" is spelled incorrectly. If it is, that might be the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the deployment-target in the config.xml is correct.

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="13.0" />
```

However, the pod file will only be updated if you **add the ios platform again** before calling `cordova prepare` or `cordova build`.

My final working solution:

```
cordova platform add ios && cordova prepare ios && cordova build ios
```

which results into

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```